# How do I set the timer tone on a Galaxy J7?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, samsung-galaxy-j7

My previous Android phone, the Galaxy Note S5, had an option for setting an MP3 ringtone for both the alarm and the timer.  I'm now using the Galaxy J7, and it appears to allow a ringtone to be set for only the alarm, by tapping on a set alarm and changing the "Alarm tone" setting.  How can I set a ringtone for the timer?  I tried tapping the timer duration, but that didn't do anything.

EDIT: Here is what the Timer screen looks like.

[image: timer screen on Galaxy J7]

EDIT: I downloaded the Google Clock app and that works ok--less friendly UI, but I can set a timer ringtone.

Comment: Add a picture? And can you be more specific about which clock app you're using?

Comment: @owlswipe, I'm using the Clock app that's included standard on the J7 (the one that has Alarm, Stopwatch, and Timer options).  I'll get a screenshot and add it.

Comment: If there's no settings menu within the clock app, try looking inside `Settings` -> `Sound`.

Comment: @owlswipe the clock app has settings for the alarm, but not for the timer.  Changing the ringtone in `Settings`->`Sound` does not change the tone for the timer.